# Call and Display React Components on an element's id using onClick Events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I really need your help here, as I am new learning **React**. Meanwhile, this question has not yet been asked and the issue is not yet raised.
I am trying to call a  to display on a element id using document. getElementById ('disp'). innerHTML. However, I am having a [OBJECT OBJECT] response as the result if I use the component as a variable, and a gibberish of JSX webpack codes if I use it as a ComponentName.
Please help me with the following codes below and the screenshots explains my point.

injex.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import React from 'react'
import Nav from './Navigation'    
import './styles.css'
import Logo from './logo1.png';

const Template = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <section className='container-fluid'>
        <header className='row bg-dark' style={ {height: '100px' }}>
          <HeaderLogo />
          <HeaderLeftColumn />
          <HeaderRightColumn />
        </header>

        <sesion className='container-fluid'>
          <section className="row">
            <div className="col-sm col-mr col-md col-lg col-xl">
              <HeaderMarquee />
            </div>
          </section>
        </sesion>
        <article className='container-fluid' id='disp' style={ {borderStyle: 'outset', borderColor: 'silver', borderRadius: '5px'} }>
          <MainBody />
        </article>

        <div className='container-fluid'>
          <div className='container'>
            <div id='statusBar' className='alert'>...</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}  

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Template />);
```

Navigation.js

```
import React from 'react'
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import './styles.css'
import CreateSchoolCategory from './components/createschoolcategory'

//this code works well when a text is just assigned to the div element
const showPaymentAPIPage = () => { 
    { document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML = `Payment API Page` }
}
```

[image]

```
//calling it as a component will return [object object] as response on the element id
const showCreateSchoolCategory = () => {
     {{ document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML = <CreateSchoolCategory /> } }
}
```

[image]

```
//calling it as a variable will return a gibberish of JSX interpreted codes on the element id.
const showCreateSchoolCategory = () => {
     {{ document.getElementById('disp').innerHTML = CreateSchoolCategory  } }
}
```

[image]

```
const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <>
       {/* <section className='text-danger'> <TestPage /> </section>  */}

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">  
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Main | Data Settings
                    </a>
                    <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a className="dropdown-item listFont" href="#" onClick={showPaymentAPIPage}>Payment API</a>
                        <a className="dropdown-item listFont" href="#" onClick={showCreateSchoolCategory}> Create School Categories</a>                                                       
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>      
    </>
  )
};

export default Nav
```

createschoolcategory.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
function headerText() {
    // const url = window.location.href;
    // if(url.includes('create-school-categories') === true){
    //     return document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = `Create New School Category`;
    // }
    // return document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = '';
    return document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = `Create New Teacher Category`;
const CreateSchoolCategory = () => {    
    
    headerText() 
    return (
        <>
            <div className='container' id="disp">
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-sm col-md col-lg col-xl'>
                        <h5 className='text-info'>Create School Categories</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>                
        </>
    )        
}

export default CreateSchoolCategory
```

Please help me!

Comment: Take your time to grasp the react basic usage from docs. In React you don't use DOM selectors, and you don't use .innerHTML. Just set a state in the component: `[showPayment, setShowPayment] = useState(false)` then you can just toggle with `setShowPayment(b => !b)` and use `showPayment` in JSX to display conditionally what you want: `{ showPayment && <CreateSchoolCategory />}`

Comment: Please check the screenshot again. The showPaymentAPI function works when I click on the link h

Comment: The showPaymentAPI works well when I click on the link firing the event. Just that, the selected DOM element is being assigned a string value. But showCreatSchoolCategory  function doesn't work if the DOM element is being assigned a Component or a Variable

Comment: That's not how React works, if you want to keep using antipatterns you are free to go but you hardly will receive any help from the community, in any case you will never be able to inject JSX through .innerHTML. You could use ReactDOM.render and React.createElement if you want an imperative API approach.